# html code rendered twice on the same page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, bundling-and-minification

I have implemented two filter attribute WebMarkupMin for HTML minification and BundleMinifyInlineJsCss to move script to the end of the page before closing of body tag.

In HTML minification page source does not contain closing of html, body, head tags so I have added one page called `WebMarkupMinConfig` through which I can add all these tags as per [this](https://github.com/Taritsyn/WebMarkupMin/wiki/ASP.NET-4.X-Extensions) documentation and declare all of them in `Global.asax.cs` file as per below:

```
 protected void Application_Start()
        {
     GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new MinifyHtmlAttribute());
     GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new ReplaceTagsAttribute());
     WebMarkupMinConfig.Configure(WebMarkupMinConfiguration.Instance); 
}
```

If I use all of above three lines it will generate HTML code twice for the same page like

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body></body>
</html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

How can I fix this? Thanks.